# Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null. In Flutter scroll_snap_list

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll-snap, flutter-pub

**Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null**

I think, reason of this error isn't in my code, because I delete it and left only

`import 'package:scroll_snap_list/scroll_snap_list.dart';`

It's error text ->

```
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/scroll_snap_list-0.9.1/lib/scroll_snap_list.dart:177:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
```

Pacakge: https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_snap_list

I read same questions on StackOverflow, and trying reinstall 'scroll_snap_list' package, and remove '^' near 'scroll_snap_list:' in pubspec.yaml

Now it requirement look like `scroll_snap_list: 0.9.1`, but i still have that error

Comment: You should probably report that on the package's repo here: https://github.com/MSVCode/scroll_snap_list/issues

Comment: Ok. thank you for your reply! I will definitely do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by upgrading flutter version to actual: `3.10.6`